# How can I reset the password saved by git from a Linux terminal?

Tags: git

I have entered the wrong password in git during cloning. Now, every time I want to clone the repository, git doesn't ask for the password from me and shows the error below:

> remote: Invalid username or password

Could anyone tell me how can I reset the saved password?

Comment: `git config --global --unset credential.helper`

Comment: thanks for the response, but I have tried that before but it did not work.

Comment: Is the password cached globally, or on a single project? Try: ` git config --global --add user.password "newPass"`

Comment: it did not work again, again I got "remote: Invalid username or password
" error. there is not any way to reset all settings of git?

Comment: i entered exactly "git config --global --add user.password "newPass", am i correct? or i need to replace user or password?

Comment: You should replace `newPass` with your own password of course. Otherwise use `git config --global --unset user.password` to remove the users password (not from the helper)

Comment: thank you so much, I applied your advice, now git config --global --get-all user.password or git config --global --get-all user.name returns nothing, but again problem did not solved !!

Comment: Are you on macOS? Maybe keychain is remembering it?

Comment: No i am in linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume for the moment that you're using a credential helper.  This is the reasonable and secure thing to do.

The easiest way to reset any credential helpers is to tell the credential helper that the password is bad and should be rejected.  Normally this occurs when your password is bad anyway, but sometimes it doesn't.  You can do this with the following (substituting `origin` if necessary):

```
$ echo "url=$(git remote get-url origin)" | git credential reject
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try to give the credential helper a hint by adding a username.  For example, if I were trying to reset my GitHub credentials, I'd write the following:

```
$ echo url=https://bk2204@github.com | git credential reject
```

Usually that should be sufficient.  It is possible if you're using one of the Microsoft-built credential helpers that they don't honor that setting, but most of the standard ones on Linux should.

Note that there is no `user.password` config setting.  The `user` group of configuration options is not used for remote servers, a secure configuration results in different passwords for different servers (which the hypothetical `user.password` would not), and storing secrets in the `.git/config` is not secure.

If none of these work, you'd need to inspect your Git configuration with `git config -l`.  You'd be looking for a credential helper (`credential.helper` or `credential.*.helper`) or some other configuration that contains credentials.  Since you haven't included that, we can't really tell you what might be going on.